# Кавычатся ли названия станций МЦК?

Tags: пунктуация, названия

Нужно ли кавычить названия станций МЦК по аналогии со станциями метро? Или корректно без кавычек, т. к. это все-таки железнодорожные станции?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 3):

Названия станций МЦК **берутся в кавычки**, подобно названиям станций метро.

Дело в том, что названия станций МЦК, как и станций метро, могут включать в себя слова *улица, бульвар* и т. п. Чтобы избежать путаницы, на письме они выделяются кавычками: станция «Улица 1905 года» (метро), станция «Шоссе Энтузиастов» (МЦК).

В железнодорожных названиях отсутствуют кавычки, потому что, как правило, в них нет родовых слов.

Answer (score 0):

**Московское центральное кольцо (МЦК)** — маршрутная линия **железнодорожного** пассажирского транспорта в Москве, частично интегрированная с метрополитеном по системе оплаты проезда и пересадкам.

Станции МЦК пишутся без кавычек, это видно из следующего материала, где в таблице   параллельно приводятся названия станций метро и железнодорожных станций.

[Московское центральное кольцо](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%86%D0%BE)

Comment: Интересно, а почему железнодорожные станции не должны кавычиться, а метровские — должны? Я что-то совсем не могу найти тут какую-то закономерность.

Answer (score 0):

[Сайт МКЖД](http://mkzd.ru/passengers/nizhegorodskaya/) пишет названия станций в кавычках. Например: транспортно-пересадочный узел «Нижегородская» (или ТПУ «Нижегородская»). Вероятно, "транспортно-пересадочный узел" следует относить скорее к остановкам наземного транспорта, чем к вокзалам и аэропортам. Но пока это не будет однозначно зафиксировано в словарях или справочниках, сложно будет утверждать определённо.